# Use \partial symbol in Stix2 Font

Tags: math-fonts, stix2

I would like to use the `\partial` symbol in the Stix2 font. In the rest of my document, I use EB Garamond for both text and math, but I don't like the appearance of the `\partial` symbol in Garamond. I had similar issues with other symbols, but was able to solve them using the following method: to use the `\star` symbol in Latin Modern rather than Garamond, I defined a new command like so :

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{LMletters}{OML}{lmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lmstar}{\mathbin}{LMletters}{63}
```

and would then use `\lmstar` instead of `\star` whenever I needed. I would like to use a similar procedure for the `\partial` symbol in Stix2. The problem is that I don't know what argument to put in place of `{OLM}{lmm}{m}{it}`. There should be some abbreviation for the stix2 font similar to `lmm` for Latin Modern, but I could not find it.

I have tried to look this up many times, but always get lost in technical explanations which my limited background in latex doesn't allow me to understand...

Comment: you are using pdflatex and the tfm version of stix i assume, not the OpenType stix font

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know the meaning of any of these words. My knowledge of latex is very basic, and I am using Overleaf. What is pdflatex, OpenType and tmf ?

Comment: ok a simpler version of same question, how are you getting garamond math?

Comment: thanks for rendering your question more simple. My preamble looks like 

\documentclass[8pt,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{LMletters}{OML}{lmm}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lmstar}{\mathbin}{LMletters}{63}

Comment: oh so you are using newtx so (mostly) times based math fonts but with garamond letters

Comment: book hasn't got an 8pt option so you will be getting 10pt (and a warning)

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. Is there no way to tune the size of text in book mode then ?

Comment: The standard book class doesn't include settings for 8pt. You can use extbook instead, but I really don't think that an 8pt book is a good idea.

Comment: Spare a thought for those of us who don't have 20/20 vision!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle There are two answers here: one based on `STIX2Math.pfb` font (pdftex) and second based on `STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf` (luatex, Unicode-math]. We can see that the symbol `\partial` differs in these two solutions. First one is slanted, second one upright. It is very interesting that these fonts have this difference.

Comment: @wipet hmm yes the type1 font comes in italic and upright but the partial looks the same to me, I added an image in my answer. The opentype version will have \partial in all the Unicode math alphabetic blocks that have Greek so will be available in several styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Basically as you showed, but using LS1 encoding for stix

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{STIXletters}{LS1}{stix2}     {m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol\partial   {\mathord}{STIXletters}{"29}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

$ \partial x $
\end{document}
```

I haven't used garamond here  so this is a stix2 partial with the default cm math.

[image]

stix has upright and italic LS1 encoded fonts but `\partial` looks same to me

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{STIXlettersup}{LS1}{stix2}     {m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol\partialup   {\mathord}{STIXlettersup}{"29}
\DeclareSymbolFont{STIXletters}{LS1}{stix2}     {m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol\partial   {\mathord}{STIXletters}{"29}

\showoutput
\begin{document}

$ \partial x + \partialup x$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your rapid and clear answer ! I would never have figured it out myself, the reason for this LS1 encoding still remains a mystery...

Comment: @dicemaster6u latex needs to know what symbol is in what position. in the standard setup \partial comes from (any) font with OML encoding which means the font has a \partial symbol in postion hex 40 but  stix2 fonts have the characters in different positions in this case hex 29,  that font encoding is known as LS1  (probably only used by stix1 and stix2 fonts but other font families could be defined with that encoding)

Answer (score 1):

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you can use `unicode-math`:

```
\setmainfont{EBGaramond-Regular}[
  BoldFont = EBGaramond-Bold,
  ItalicFont = EBGaramond-Italic,
  BoldItalicFont = EBGaramond-BoldItalic
]
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}[Scale=MatchUppercase]
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[Range={\partial}, Scale=MatchUppercase]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what is LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX ? Can I use these features with Overleaf ?

Comment: Yes. Overleaf lets you select your TeX engine. In the Menu on the left, change your compiler from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX. As of 2024, however, some publishers still require you to use PDFLaTeX.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! These words stayed a big mystery to me for a long time. I would have thought it was that easy to switch.